# Is it possible to apply progressive overload on squat with +10 kg resistance increments by resistance bands?

Tags: progress, resistancetraining

I am wondering is it possible to progress on squat with +10 kg resistance band increments. My squat progress will be similar to the following program:

5 * 3 60 kg

5 * 4 60 kg

5 * 5 60 kg

5 * 3 70 kg

5 * 4 70 kg

5 * 5 70 kg

5 * 3 80 kg

5 * 4 80 kg

5 * 5 80 kg

I fear to hit weightlifting plateau. Also, any adjustment advice on reps will be appreciated. And how long I can progress with this progression, can I get long term results such as 150 kg squat with this progression. Thanks.

Comment: This is the entire Bowflex concept in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know how far you can go with this. However, this is a progressive overload scheme, yes. Adding deloads for a week on every 3rd, or 4th, or 5th week will definitely help. In addition, if you are stuck, you can always change your progression scheme. Here you are adding reps, at some point you can stop adding reps and adding sets. Maybe you can add weight and do the same set x rep.

I would definitely use microloading. As a beginner, I am sure you can get great use of linear progression.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that resistance bands won’t provide constant force across their range of stretch. And, this will be especially pronounced once more than one band is used.

I wouldn’t use them for anything other than warming up / mobility work or hi-rep workouts. That said you could use them with jump squats to develop explosivity. Or as a single band added to a weight loaded bar.